# How can I restrict the access to my website (Azure Static Website) to the people in my Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I came across the [following service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) in Azure, called Azure Static Website, which allows me to store a static website in my storage account.

It works and I am able to use it.

However, I would like to restrict the access of the website (not the resources, but the actual website) to the people that are in my Azure Active Directory.

In the website's configuration, I do not see anything to enable this:

[image: Access policy of the website]

**Question**

Is it possible to restrict the access to my Azure Static Website to the people in my Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to understand that there could be two possibilities you are referring to:

**1-** Limit access to the website to specific users

**2-** Limit access to website resources(content stored in $web container) to specific users.

**For option 1:** Anyone that knows the URI to your website will be able to access it, there are no option to restrict the access based on RBAC.

**Option 2:** You can control who can access the resources stored on the $web container via SAS, Rbac(AD) or Keys, more on can be read on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/check-access)

Comment: And there are no other option to control the access to the website?

Comment: @kzrystof, not currently, I'd recommend to leave a comment in feedback.azure.com/forums/217298 as a possible feature request, and I'll discuss next week with the product team to see if it could be implemented

Comment: I posted the suggestion as offered: [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/36453091-enable-authorization-to-the-azure-static-websites)

Answer (score 0):

You host it as an [Azure Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/) and easily do it.

1. Create a Github or Azure DevOps repo with your code
2. Register an App with Azure Active Directory

   - Make note of the `client_id`, `client_secret` and `tenant_id`
3. Create the Azure Static Web App resource

   - When creating the resource, connect the repo
4. After the resource is created, add two Application Setting under `Configuration`

   - `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`
   - `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`
5. Create a `staticwebapp.config.json` file in the correct directory
6. Add the necessary items [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration)

   - **IMPORTANT**: Leave the `AZURE_CLEINT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` in the file below. Do not substitute it in the file. The Application Setting substitute these values during runtime.
   - **Example**:

```
{
    "routes": [
      {
        "route": "/*",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
      }
    ],
    "responseOverrides": {
      "401": {
        "statusCode": 302,
        "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad"
      }
    },
    "auth": {
        "identityProviders": {
          "azureActiveDirectory": {
            "registration": {
              "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>/v2.0",
              "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
              "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

See this guys [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnwRpEM6GR8) for step by step.